# How disable radio button without using disabled attribute?

Tags: jquery

I have to keep radio button non-clickable (disabled state) without using disabled attribute. how can i do that ?

I checked using below code. but it is not working completely.It allows to click. After click on radio it doesn't get selected but calling onclick method of that radio element.

```
 $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){return false; });      
 <html:radio onclick="javascript:enableAll();" name="Employee" />Status
```

Comment: why you don't want to user disable attribute? any specific reason?

Comment: I need to bang in a nail without using a hammer. Can you help me? BAsically, why would you even try to do something without using the intended tool for the job? Sure you can use a shoe to bang in a nail - but it wont work very well!

Comment: Is this because you cant work out how to dynamically enable/disable using the `disabled` attribute?

Comment: if i use disabled attribute. on next -preview page. I am not getting it's value.

Comment: pointer-events:none? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the disabled attribute and at the same time have a hidden input right next to it who also keeps the value, so on the next preview page you can get the value from that hidden input.

Note. this is a workaround.

Comment: I wouldnt even call that a workaround, to me thats the right tool for the job.